# For loop over array in array AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, arrays

How do I iterate over this array in array in AngularJS `Javascript` code:

```
[[4,5,6,4,8.7]]
```

Comment: on the javascriptside or on the view?

Comment: on the javascript side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is an array.

Use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for iteration.

In this case, each item is an array, and therefore you have an inner forEach as well.

Angular also has a method for forEach. It's called [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach).
 You can use it if you want to or need to support ancient browsers.

```js
[[4,5,6,4,8.7]].forEach(function(arr){ arr.forEach(function(item){ console.log(item) }) } );
```

P.s. to avoid the smartass that is going to say that [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) wont work on IE8, then it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'angular.forEach'.

```
  angular.forEach([[4,5,6,4,8.7]], function(arr){
     angular.forEach(arr, function(value){
       console.log(value);
     })
  });
```